# Calling a method from another Form in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, entity-framework

I want that when I insert or update records in another form (`Form2`), the `DataGridView` on `Form1` should automatically refresh (call `btnRefresh`) after each operation or *preferably* wait until all change operations have finished, and update the `DataGridView` form `Form2`'s closing event with all changes.

I believe in VB.NET this is achieved with `Form1.DataGridView.Refresh`, but I am not sure in C#. I was told that I pass the reference of the `DataGridView` on `Form1` to `Form2` using properties but since I'm new to C#, I didn't know how to. How can I resolve this issue?

My refresh button code:

```
private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GVThesis.DataSource = thesisRepository.GetThesis();
    GVThesis.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Look into the Observer design pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firs, wrap your refresh code into a method of its own, and call that from your click event handler method, like so:

```
    private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        this.RefreshData();
    }

    public void RefreshData()
    {
        GVThesis.DataSource = thesisRepository.GetThesis(); 
        GVThesis.Refresh(); 
    }
```

Then, asuming you are instantiating and launching the new form (Form2) from your Form1, simply go into the code of Form2 and create yourself a new constructor overload which will accept a reference to Form1, and store it in a private variable, like so:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 frm1;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(Form1 otherForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.frm1 = otherForm;
    }
}
```

Then you can call the "refresh" from anywhere you like in Form2 like so:

```
this.frm1.RefreshData();
```

**EDIT:**
I created a small sample, I cannot upload it here...but here is a screenshot of both the program itself in VS, as well as a screenshot of the result of running it and performing the function...hopefully that will help.
The program (zoom your view if it appears too small)
[image: The Program in VS 2010]

The Result:
[image: A function on Form1, called from Form2]

Comment: I tried using your solution.
But I get the NullReferenceException was unhandled error.

By the way the way I Form2 is like this:
    otherForm Form2 = new otherForm();
    Form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    Form2.ShowDialog(this);

Comment: I updated the answer with a couple screenshots of a sample app that performs, essentially, what I believe you are trying to do. Have  alook and let me know what you think.

Comment: Oh, I see by your comment, you need to pass a reference to Form1 into the constructor, or at least as a parameter of a call, to Form2. Passing 'this' into the .ShowDialog method will not do the trick. Take a close look at the screenshots I posted, you should see the way to do it there. Good luck!