# calling a method from another form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Mainform like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    string FileName = "";

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void goToToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void menuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem ) sender;

        switch (menuItem.Name.Replace("ToolStripMenuItem",""))
        {
            case "new":
                MenuItemNew();
                break; 
            case "open" :
                MenuItemOpen();
                break;
            case "save":
                MenuItemSave();
                break;
            case "saveAs" :
                MenuItemSaveAs();
                break;
          case "exit" :
                MenuItemExit();
                break;
            case "selectAll" :
                MenuItemSelectAll();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void MenuItemSelectAll()
    {
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }

    private void MenuItemExit()
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void MenuItemSaveAs()
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Text Document |*.txt";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName);
            writer.Write(textBox.Text);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    private void MenuItemSave()
    {
        if (FileName == "")
        {
            MenuItemSaveAs();
        }
        else
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FileName);
            writer.Write(textBox.Text);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    private void MenuItemOpen()
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Text Document|*.txt";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileName = ofd.FileName;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
            textBox.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    private void MenuItemNew()
    {
        if (textBox.Text == "")
        {
            textBox.Text = String.Empty;
        }
        else
            this.Show();
            Newform sistema=new Newform();
        sistema.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

And a Newform like this:

```
public partial class Newform : Form
{
    public Newform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void dontsave_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

When save is clicked in my new form, I need MenuItemSaveAs to open in my main form.

Comment: well can u tell me whats the problem?

Comment: I thought that's what you should tell me and others, not me :)

Comment: This may help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469423/calling-a-method-from-another-form-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: First you need to have a reference to your MainForm in NewForm, then you can make the MenuItemOpen public and invoke it where ever you want in NewForm.

Comment: @KingKing - The idea of SO is to answer questions not antagonize the question askers.  Just saying.

Comment: @Hogan but the question is very basic, no need to search on Google, such a question **has been asked** at least dozens of times since I've signed up SO and used SO frequently 4 months ago. (That's what I've read, not all).

Comment: @KingKing - Then you should click close and flag as duplicate with a pointer to the same question somewhere else. Being nasty to the person asking the question is not a good thing -- imagine if you didn't know SO and was asking a question.  Also, make sure it is a dup -- Angus' dup pointer was not the same question -- for example.

Comment: @Hogan it's not a duplicate, although the idea to solve it can be found in the so-called *duplicated questions*.

Comment: @KingKing - I just go by what is written on meta and talked about on the podcast.  Please post what your point is on meta, I'd like to understand exactly what you are getting at -- that is a good place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first

```
 public void MenuItemSaveAs()
```

then

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();   
    ((MainForm)Parent).MenuItemSaveAs()
}
```

This assumes that your form is a child of MainForm.  If it isn't then you will need to pass a reference to MainForm into the constructor of the form and save it locally.  (There is also a way to always find the main form of the current program but I don't think this is an elegant way to solve the problem.)

Comment: Error The name 'parent' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @MelodyHajian - Please use `P` not `p` - caps matter.

Comment: Please **NOTE** that, this is `C#`, not `C++`

Comment: Error 'Notepad.MainForm.MenuItemSaveAs()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @MelodyHajian You need to make that method public : `public void MenuItemSaveAs()`

Answer (score 1):

Melody, the problem really is in the design. A form should not call GUI elements in another form. This can lead to "spaghetti" code that is extremely hard to maintain. If it's the main form you're trying to manipulate in this way, you can rely on it being around, but it's still a violation of best practices. If you were to try to manipulate other forms this way, you would have to deal with the possibility the form does not exist (hasn't been created yet, or has been disposed).

If code needs to manipulate the GUI of a form, said code should be within that form.

Comment: While this is all true, this doesn't provide an answer for how it *should* be done to *not* violate these principles.